# How should one deal with questions that can be answered by copy/pasting from a manual page?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, scope

Example:

[How download multiple files with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802239/how-download-multiple-files-with-curl)

The person is unsure how to store results from several different URLs in different files.
The manual page describes how to do exactly that.

In the past I have answered several questions by copy pasting from a man page and maybe providing additional examples.

Is that sort of answer something the general community wants to see?
How about questions like that?

If I were to vote to close such questions, which reason should be given?

Comment: In 99% of cases, there's a solid duplicate that exists for the given question.

Comment: To be clear, there is _nothing, whatsoever,_ wrong with answers that are (*properly linked & attributed) regurgitations of documentation tailored to an OP's use case; Stack Overflow exists to be a repository of knowledge, documentation is definitely useful knowledge. But 99 times out of 100, a question like that isn't the first, and there's a (hopefully good) duplicate for it somewhere.

Comment: Note that, there is positively something wrong, unlike @zcoop98's assertion, with copying and pasting from a man page without attribution. Yes, provide examples tailored to the OP's specific use case. Yes, search for a duplicate first before answering. But please don't plagiarize other people's works by copying them verbatim without mentioning the source.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Okay, yes– I just kind of assumed providing attribution was a given. I edited in a fix of wording though just to address your point.

Comment: @zcoop98 I'm always going to speak up when people give hyperbolic quotations like "*nothing, whatsoever* wrong". There are things wrong with regurgitations of documentation; plagiarism is just one of them. Another is when there is an error in the documentation, and users spread that far and wide before the original publishers get the chance to amend it. That's another reason to provide attribution of course, and a reason for people to check the attributed source before swallowing what's given. It was a problem with Stack Overflow Documentation as well, before it got kicked out.

Answer (score -4):

1. Trivial questions will more likely than not have duplicates.
2. Plagiarism is bad, m'kay - but it's cool to answer so long as you say "this is from the man page"
3. Duplicating wrong docs is bad, m'kay

To be honest I don't think authors of man pages are super worried about proper attribution. They'll be happy if the questions are answered in any way (including copy-pasting manuals without attribution) instead of ending up on their mailing list - or at least that's what I think. In other cases the docs are ancient and the author is not even indicated.

I think it's up to you if you want to score a "quick 15 rep" by answering a duplicate, or vote to close as a duplicate and instead look for more interesting questions.

Comment: What is "m'kay"? And what does plagiarism have to do with the question, which is not about *attribution*? (which goes without saying)

Comment: It's a reference to a popular animated show - south park. When you state something obvious, it doesn't hurt to follow that up by m'kay. About plagiarism - I would ask the people providing comments about plagiarism the same question.

Comment: *[m'kay](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%27kay#English)* - *"Nasalized variant of "okay". Perhaps made popular by frequent appearance in the cartoon South Park as Mr Mackey's catchphrase; earlier, apparently only in linguistic transcriptions of speech. ... Interjection (informal) Okay; an expression of acknowledgment or affirmation, now sometimes used in an ironic or condescending sense."*